# Encoding difference in XMTYPE columns between two Oracle instances

Tags: oracle, encoding, oracle11gr2, xmltype

We use `XMLTYPE` in our production Oracle database (`11.2.0.3.0`), which is hosted in an Amazon server (`Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.9`), and we are querying it from our Java application (`JDK 1.8`).

We never had issues in production, but last week we set up an RDS instance (`11.2.0.4.0`), and imported a copy of the production database, to test the application with this kind of database.

When trying to query a table with XMLTYPE, the following exception was thrown:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid character encountered in
        at oracle.sql.CharacterSet.failUTFConversion(CharacterSet.java:2865)
        at oracle.sql.CharacterSetAL32UTF8.toString(CharacterSetAL32UTF8.java:186)
        at oracle.xdb.XMLType.processString(XMLType.java:3294)
        at oracle.xdb.XMLType.processThin(XMLType.java:3415)
        at oracle.xdb.XMLType.<init>(XMLType.java:1531)
        at oracle.xdb.XMLType.createXML(XMLType.java:926)
        at oracle.xdb.XMLType.createXML(XMLType.java:900)
```

After some debugging, we found that the culprit was this `XMLTYPE`:

```
<HotelMultimediaStore>
  <code>032141@32141@FareProperty@NRE</code>
  <commercialName>NO REEMBOLSABLE</commercialName>
  <description>SE CARGARÃƒï¿½ EL 100% DEL TOTAL DE LA ESTANCIA
CANCELACIÃƒâ€œN: 100% DEL TOTAL DE LA ESTANCIA, SI CANCELA MODIFICA LA ESTANCIA O NÃƒÅ¡MERO DE PERSONAS. O NO SE PRESENTA</description>
  <elementType>FareProperty</elementType>
  <elementCode>NRE#null</elementCode>
  <vendorCode>032141</vendorCode>
  <hotelCode>32141</hotelCode>
</HotelMultimediaStore>
```

We deleted it from the RDS table and all the rest worked, but we never knew why, because the content in the production environment was exactly the same (from what we could see).

We did a bit of additional research and it seems the `XMLTYPE` characters are not encoded in the same way in both databases. For example in production we have double quotes `"` in some text, but in the new RDS instance it seems that it has been automatically encoded to `&quot;` during the import (which seems correct, this was done by mistake in our application, we should encode those before inserting).

Furthermore, when trying to execute an `extractValue( COLUMN,'//text()')`, it worked correctly in the RDS instance, but failed to do so in the production environment, throwing this exception after 30 seconds:

```
ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
```

We checked the parameters of both the [RDS instance](https://pastebin.com/sc0ZkHjh) and our [production environment](https://pastebin.com/J09nJwRt) and found nothing strange.

Any ideas about what could be going on?

The Java Oracle libraries we use, just in case:

```
oracle.jdbc:oracleDriver:11.2.0.2.0
oracle:orai18n:11.2.0.2.0
oracle:orai18n-collation:11.2.0.2.0
oracle:xdb:11.2.0.2.0
oracle:xmlparserv2:11.2.0.2.0`
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the issue, but some of your NLS database parameters don't match between your servers - your `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` is "UTF8" in Production and "AL16UTF16" in RDS, for example. Are you using the 11g default CLOB storage for these XMLTYPE columns?

Comment: You are right, but I thought that the `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET`was only used for the `NVARCHAR2` column type. Is it also used for the XMLTYPE columns? And yes, we use the default CLOB storage.

Comment: How did you get the culprit (the value of the XMLType column) when it has invalid character encountered in?

Comment: We did a debug with a custom Java class loading the table row by row.